# Hessian of distance function from a Jordan curve

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Assume that $\gamma$ is $C^2$ Jordan curve in $\mathbf{R}^3$ and let $f(x)=d^2(x,\gamma)$. Is there any known formula for the hessian of $f$ near $\gamma$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are some formulas.  Let's assume you are close-enough to the curve that the geometric tubular neighbourhood theorem applies, i.e. there is a unique closest point to $x$ in the curve $\gamma$. Call it $\pi(x)$.  $\pi : \nu C \to \gamma$ is a smooth map, where $\nu \gamma$ is an open tubular neighbourhood of the curve $\gamma$.

This gives you the formula:

$$d^2(x,\gamma) = d^2(x,\pi(x)) = (x-\pi(x))\cdot (x-\pi(x))$$

so

$$D_x(d^2(x,\gamma)) = 2(I - D_x\pi)\cdot (I - \pi(x))$$

i.e.

$$D_x(d^2(x,\gamma))(v) = 2(v-D_x\pi(v)) \cdot (v - \pi(x))$$

$$H_x(d^2(x,\gamma) )(v,w) = D^2_x(v,w) = -2H_x\pi(v,w) \cdot (x-\pi(x)) -2(w-D_x\pi(w)) \cdot (v-D\pi_x(v)) $$

The above is valid for any closed submanifold of a Euclidean space ($\mathbb R^n$).   $H$ denotes the [Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix).